# Writing to prospective advisors who co-authored a paper

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, application, email

I wrote an enquiry mail about graduate positions to a Professor who is working in the field I am interested in. I cited a paper authored by the professor in my e-mail. The paper is co-authored by another professor in the same department, whom I wish to write to as well. They share research interests, have co-authored many papers and often co-supervise students. Would it be wrong to cite the same paper again in my e-mail to the second professor? I am worried that the two e-mails may end up looking identical.

Comment: Structure it differently then...

Comment: @SolarMike so it's ok if the content seems identical?

Comment: If you are equally happy to work with either of them you could structure a letter that focuses more on the topic than the professor and send it to both of them "I'd like to work with one or both of you" phrasing, perhaps.

Comment: Depending on the field you are in, the order of authorship might give you more information. It's possible the work you are referring to is mostly done in one lab or the other, with the second person mostly providing support, or it may be a true close collaboration. It might be hard to figure out which is the case, but you should probably investigate as well as you are able to. Is one of these professors a more senior person? Another situation that comes up in my field is that a senior person is very busy and they have actual tenure track faculty that basically work under them.